# The gradient in the update_step() function in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, optimization, deep-learning, gradient

In tf.Keras , the function update_step() is used by an optimizer to update the variables at every iteration given the variable and the gradient. I want to know if this gradient is the full gradient of all the samples in the batch or the gradient for a sample in the batch?
thank you

Comment: the gradient of the loss wrt the weights, so the batch... otherwise usually is called jacobian instead of gradient (when it's referred to each sample)

Comment: @Alberto Sinigaglia thank you, is it possible in Keras to get the gradients  referred to each sample of a batch (for example, in the function on_train_batch_end)?

Comment: yes, using `tf.GradientTape` you can get the jacobian, which should be what you are looking for